# Why is it "unserem" in this sentence?

Tags: accusative, possessive-pronoun

> Manche sprechen von einer neuen Evolution, die das Leben auf **unserem**
>   Planeten fundamental verändern könnte.

I take the case to be accusative because of "auf" and the verb "verändern" which has the meaning of change and movement, and I take the gender to be masculine. And that is why it is "Planet**en**" and not "planet". But then shouldn't it be "unseren" too?

Comment: *Unserem* is dative and dative only: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/unser#Possessivpronomen,_1._Person_Plural

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word “Planet” is still singular as seen here. Certain word endings change based on what precedes them.

You can read more [here](https://courses.dcs.wisc.edu/wp/readinggerman/genitive-dative-cases/) about the endings (go to the last paragraph). One example they cite is “Student.” Let’s apply it:

> Ich helfe meinem Studenten.
>   I help my student.
>
> Ich helfe meinen Studenten.
>   I help my students.

These words largely have to be memorized.

Edit: As @johnl notes, this is also not in accusative. The phrase “on our planet,” which indicates a place, is in this case an example of the dative.

However, some word endings would also change for the accusative. So, the accusative for “Planet” would still have the same ending. At that point, you rely on the case and the article to indicate whether it’s plural or singular. If “Planet” is in the accusative and *plural*, it would be preceded by “die” and not “den.”

In other words:

> Accusative: *den* Planeten (singular), *die* Planeten (plural)

Compare this to:

> Dative: *dem* Planeten (singular), *den* Planeten (plural)

This is why the entire sentence/context needs to be considered.

Comment: I think the crucial mistake here might be the (mis)identification of _unserem Planeten_ in the example as an accusative. Perhaps you want to address that?

Comment: @johnl Isn't *planeten* accusative here?

Comment: No, it is the dative. The “planet” is neither a direct object nor a destination here. I modified my answer above to reflect that. Thanks @johnl

Answer (score 1):

The distinction isn't about change and movement or not, but about **direction vs location**.

The verb *verändern* can take a direction, but that's obviously the direction of change, not the place where the change happens.

> Sie **verändert** das Kuchenrezept ihrer Oma **über den guten Geschmack hinaus.**
>
> Paul hat sich in diesem Seminar sehr **zum Besseren verändert**.

In the latter example it's both preposition+dative, because *zu* always takes dative, and always means a direction.

Comment: Thank you for the point. I think you told me that before. But you didn't answer the question!

Comment: It's *Planeten* because it is dative case! It's a location, not a direction.

Comment: No, as explained in the other anwer, it is *planeten* because it is an exception. If it was a normale dative, it wouldn't get -en, because it is masculine.

Comment: It's normal for n-declination. Most n-declined nouns have an -e in nominative singular case, but not all of them. See the huge list of alternative endings at the end of https://mein-deutschbuch.de/n-deklination.html, and -et isn't even listed there, though Poet, Asket, Planet, Athlet, Magnet, … are all n-declined.